# Why can't I print %c after %s in my code?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm new to C programming, and I'm learning to get string input. I try to use malloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);    
    
    printf("%s ",s[2]);
    printf("%c",s[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, nothing is printed. But when I put the %c printf before the %s printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);    
    printf("%c",s[2]);
    printf("%s ",s[2]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

It runs and shows the result of `printf("%c",s[2]);`. Why is this happening? Does `printf` clear memory in `char s`?

Comment: The argument corresponding to `%s` has to be a string. `s[2]` is a single character, not a string, so you caused undefined behavior.

Comment: Modern compilers will warn you about mismatches between the format string and the arguments. Be sure to enable the warnings. Then read the warnings and fix the warnings. If you need help enabling or viewing warnings, you need to provide information about the compiler and/or IDE that you're using.

Comment: if you want to start from char 3 use `&s[2]` in the printf. ie pass in the address of the third char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a string is just an array of `char`, which we save as a `char *`: a location in the computer's memory where we have stored our array of `char`'s (a *memory address* , or, a *pointer*).

The `%c` flag tells `printf` to process a single character (i.e. `s[2]`).

The `%s` flag, however, tells `printf` to process an entire string at the *memory address* stored at `s[2]`. If, for example, `s[2] = 'A'`, then `printf` will try to access a string stored at memory location `'A'`. In ASCII, the letter `'A'` is just the integer `65`, which is not a valid memory location and thus, the program will error.

In the first instance, the program is probably exiting (due to the error in using `%s`) before the `printf` using `%c` outputs, whereas in the second instance, the `printf` using `%c` outputs before the error occurs.